# Handle same check box at multiple places

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am very new to HTML,CSS,Javascript coding. 
I have to add some check box in the page and there are multiple tabs in the same single page.

If I select or deselect any check box, checkbox checks from all the places should be changed.

Can anybody tell me how to do so using HTML,CSS, Javascript?

Comment: Your question is very general. It sounds like "teach JavaScript to me", or "write my code". The best thing would be to post some code to show what you have tried (either here or for example on jsfiddle) and write a specific question about it.

Comment: @RoToRa

thanks for your suggestion but As I told **"I am very new to HTML,CSS,Javascript coding."** 

_and currently I need to use it for only my that specific problem._

Comment: @user1027702: The problem is you didn't post a specific problem. "Checkbox checks ... should be changed" could be mean anything. Also it's ok to be a beginner, but we need something to "build on". Or do you think random pieces of code will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript - Select All checkbox in form</title>
<script>
var fieldName='chkName';

function selectall(){
  var i=document.frm.elements.length;
  var e=document.frm.elements;
  var name=new Array();
  var value=new Array();
  var j=0;
  for(var k=0;k<i;k++)
  {
    if(document.frm.elements[k].name==fieldName)
    {
      if(document.frm.elements[k].checked==true){
        value[j]=document.frm.elements[k].value;
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
  checkSelect();
}
function selectCheck(obj)
{
 var i=document.frm.elements.length;
  for(var k=0;k<i;k++)
  {
    if(document.frm.elements[k].name==fieldName)
    {
      document.frm.elements[k].checked=obj;
    }
  }
  selectall();
}

function selectallMe()
{
  if(document.frm.allCheck.checked==true)
  {
   selectCheck(true);
  }
  else
  {
    selectCheck(false);
  }
}
function checkSelect()
{
 var i=document.frm.elements.length;
 var berror=true;
  for(var k=0;k<i;k++)
  {
    if(document.frm.elements[k].name==fieldName)
    {
      if(document.frm.elements[k].checked==false)
      {
        berror=false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(berror==false)
  {
    document.frm.allCheck.checked=false;
  }
  else
  {
    document.frm.allCheck.checked=true;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frm">
select all :<input type="checkbox" name="allCheck" onClick="selectallMe()">
<hr><br>
1  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
2  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
3  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
4  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
5  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
6  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
7  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
8  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
9  :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
10 :<input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onClick="selectall()"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give those checkboxes some same name, and do:

```
function checkAll() {
var field = document.your_form_name.your_checkbox_name;
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = true ;
}
```

Hope that helps